# How do I add another ImportXML function to the same cell and have that XML function activate if another cell has specific text in it?

Tags: if-statement

I need help with having E17 change depending on what D17 cell has.

`=IF(RegExMatch(D17,"Amazon"), ImportXML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/"&C17,"//span[@id='productTitle']"))`

How do I add another **ImportXML** function if **D17** has *Walmart* or *Overstock* is in the cell?

I'll need help finding the Walmart search link as well so when D17 has "Walmart" auto inputted it searches the Walmart registry for the IN#'s title. Thank you! Hope I provided enough insight. I own an eCommerce business and this will help me a lot.

If you can find a way to do it with any market site that would help a lot as well.

[Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZEar.png)

Comment: as a start I can't make your function work: ```=IMPORTXML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M9F6P2G", "//span[@id='productTitle']")```returns ```#N/A```

Comment: That function is working for me but I want to allow multiple different supplier sites to be tracked depending on what text is put into C17